# Does is it possible to check social media url status by php?

Tags: php

Existence of an URL can be checked by checking the status code in the response header. The status code 200 is Standard response for successful HTTP requests and status code 404 means URL doesn’t exist.

```
<?php  

$url = "https://www.facebook.com/shahidulmh/posts/pfbid02MfSTMjTYjndf4qCsf1qfQSTX9PfCD6FukYozjSrdmiqNK38AkykVBcJ8kD1qU3pYl?";
  

$headers = @get_headers($url);
  

if($headers && strpos( $headers[0], '200')) {
    $status = "URL Exist";
}
else {
    $status = "URL Doesn't Exist";
}
  
// Display result
echo($status);
?>
```

i am trying this code.but status shown 302.

Comment: 302 means the content was moved. So you need to follow the Location specified in the response headers to find out where to look next. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302

Answer (score 1):

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

How about this? You need to decide how you'll handle status beginning 1, 3, and 5

And you can of course build on the logic to do further division on specific response codes, if needed

```
if($headers) {
    switch(substr($headers[0], 9, 1)) {
        case '1':
            $status = "Informational message. Decide what logic to do here";
            break;
        case '2':
            $status = "URL Exist";
            break;
        case '3':
            $status = "Redirection message. Decide what logic to do here";
            break;
        case '4':
            $status = "URL Doesn't Exist";
            break;
        case '5':
            $status = "Server error. Decide what logic to do here";
            break;
    }
}
else {
    $status = "URL Doesn't Exist";
}
```